# Force on circular loop

Tags: electromagnetism

Would the forces between two circular loops, carrying currents in the same direction, be attractive or repulsive?
Would the forces between two circular loops, carrying current in the opposite directions, be attractive or repulsive? 
How to find a force acting on a circular loop? 
Please explain with a picture.

Comment: Have you read this: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/curloo.html

Answer (score 1):

This picture sums up the two scenarios pretty well:

[image]

To give a little bit of context as to what is happening in each scenario:

### 1. When the current in each loop is in the same direction

Using the RH rule, you can determine the direction of the magnetic field. Curl your right hand in the direction of the current along the wire and your thumb points in the direction of the magnetic field.

The field from this loop is similar to the field of a magnet as is shown in the diagram.

When the two currents go the same direction, the magnetic fields point the same direction so when you put them next to one another, the loops will be attracted as if they were two magnets aligned the same direction.

### 2. When the current goes in opposite directions

You apply the same logic as above to find the direction of the induced magnetic field.

This time the magnetic fields point opposite directions, analogous to having two magnets with like ends facing each other.

As with when you put the like ends of magnets together, they repel one another.

Comment: https://www.britannica.com/science/magnetism/Repulsion-or-attraction-between-two-magnetic-dipoles                                                      Here it is written when loops are placed side by side same current carrying loops repel and when they are placed in other way same current carrying loops attract.